# getAllCellInfo() returns null android API Level 28.how to solve this?

Tags: android

I work on a project that goes to collect all cells information that observed by phone. I have used TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() method, but it always returns null.

My code is:

```
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.cell_value);
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = null;
    telephonyManage telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    cellInfoList = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (cellInfoList == null) {
        tv.setText("getAllCellInfo() is null");
    } 
    else if (cellInfoList.size() == 0) {
        tv.setText("The base station list is empty");
    }
    else{
           CellInfo cellInfo = cellInfoList.get(0);
           if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                //4G
                CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfo;
                tv.setText(cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength().getLevel() + " , " + cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength().getAsuLevel());
            }
            else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                //2G
                CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfo;
                tv.setText(cellInfoGsm.getCellSignalStrength().getLevel() + " , " + cellInfoGsm.getCellSignalStrength().getAsuLevel());
            }
            else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo;
                tv.setText(cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength().getLevel() + " , " + cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength().getAsuLevel());
            }
    }
```

Also, I added the following permission to AndroidManifest.xml:
INTERNET, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION .

I'm working on android 4.2 API level 28.